# Regenerated R file, but not detecting previous view controls

Tags: android

I have regenerated my R file via cleaning the proejct but now the problem is more complex. All my previous view controls arnt detected. What should I do.

```
package newsapp.com;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import newsapp.com.PullToRefreshListView.OnRefreshListener;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import facebook.src.com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import facebook.src.com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import facebook.src.com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import facebook.src.com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
```

Comment: show your import area(below packagename).

Comment: Try to restart your eclipse. Or just import the project from your local history, if you're having local history.

Comment: i tried, but still the same issue, i had seen my gen folder doenst contain R file. '

Comment: Your console must be showing some error

Comment: thanks...you were right my console was showing an error, now its ok i got it regenerated. Thanks a lot....

Comment: U r not at all interested in sharing problem with us

Comment: yes...it is ok, i got it done

Comment: If u can share how u get rid of it,will be helpful for others.and mark ur answer as accepted one.

Comment: ok....in android you cannot have icon and drawable resource with capital letters. So i was haveing an image as GreenBolt.png so which should have been greenbolt.png. You need to wait for 2 days before accepting your own answer. Thanks for helping out all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do Project->Clean and rebuild your program.

Comment: ohh i got it. click on problem view in eclipse. check that is there any resources problem. If eclipse not get any resource then it cant rebuild project

Answer (score 6):

R.java is autogenerated on build. It's content is based on the resource files (including layouts and preferences).

When you deleted it, it was recreated, but if you create your own, you will get into trouble as the build system will not replace it.

You can simply delete it again (manually or by choosing Project->Clean) and rebuild your program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem "R cannot be resolved" happens when you change your package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file. It uses your Android package name to create a subdirectory under the "gen" directory where it stores the R.java file.

R is an automatically generated class that holds the constants used to identify your Resources. If you don't have an R.java file.I would recommend closing and reopening your project or going to >Project > Build all (and selecting "Build Automatically" )

Answer (score 0):

ok....in android you cannot have icon and drawable resource with capital letters. So i was having an image as **GreenBolt.png** so which should have been **greenbolt.png**. You need to wait for 2 days before accepting your own answer. Thanks for helping out all of you.